# Can't use the Design mode in Qt Quick projects

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have recently installed Qt Creator 5.12. I can use the edit mode to write codes and can the successfully build and run projects with MinGw compiler. However, I have problems with using the Design mode. The library of objects doesn't allow me to drag any of the the objects to my main window.
How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Stackoverflow is more about programming problems, than how to use a specific IDE.

Comment: @LtWorf the questions related to IDEs are also valid in SO.